# redux store variable not refreshing inside method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, antd

I am currently trying to implement an upload component using antd design.

I have a variable that I map state to props called progress. This variable is used to set the upload progress of the upload component.

When console logging inside the main function M3UUpload, the variable is perfectly showing as expected

However, I am also using progress inside another function called checkProgress. In all cases, progress shows as undefined.

Please find a code sample below:

````
import { Row, Col, Upload, Button, message } from 'antd';

import Layout from '../Layout';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import { _upload_m3u } from '../../../shared/actionCreators/m3u';


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators(
    { upload: _upload_m3u },
    dispatch,
  ),
});

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ m3u_upload: state.m3us.pending });

const M3UUpload = ({
  m3u_upload: { progress, channels },
  actions: { upload }
}) => {
  const [displayUpload, setDisplayUpload] = React.useState(true);
  const showUpload = () => setDisplayUpload(true);
  const hideUpload = () => setDisplayUpload(false);

  const checkProgress = (onSuccess, onProgress) => setTimeout (() => {
    console.log(progress) ---> undefined x3
    if (progress === 100){
      onSuccess("ok");
    } else {
      onProgress({percent: progress});
      checkProgress(onSuccess, onProgress);
    }  
  }, 1000);

  const dummyRequest = ({ file, onSuccess, onProgress }) => checkProgress(onSuccess, onProgress);

  const beforeUpload = (file, fileList) => {
    upload({ size: file.size, path: file.path })
  };

  const onChange = info => {
    switch (info.file.status) {
      case "done":
        //console.log({m3u_upload});

        break;
      case "uploading":
        //info.file.percent = progress;
        break;
      default:
        message.error(`${info.file.name} file upload failed.`);
        break;
    }
  };

  console.log(progress) --> 25, 50, 100

  return (
    <Layout>
        <div>
            <Row>
                <Col span={12}>
                <Upload
                  accept=".m3u"
                  customRequest={dummyRequest}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  beforeUpload={beforeUpload}
                >
                  <Button>Choose File</Button>
                </Upload>
                </Col>
                <Col span={12}>
                    Download from URL
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(M3UUpload); ```
````

Comment: Can you please add more details around the what you actually want to happen and what is going wrong?

Comment: I have console logged in 2 places: in checkProgress, always undefined but in the main function: 25, 50, 100. The example has been updated

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error you are actually facing  because of incomplete information, but it looks like there is some issue in the following function.

```
const checkProgress = (onSuccess, onProgress) => setTimeout (() => {
    if (progress === 100){
      onSuccess("ok");
    } else {
      onProgress({percent: progress});
      checkProgress(onSuccess, onProgress, progress);
    }  
  }, 1000);
```

`checkProgress` function receives two parameters, `onSuccess` and `onProgress`. 
in the else condition you are passing 3, `checkProgress(onSuccess, onProgress, progress);`

Can you send the code example where you are trying to render the `M3UUpload` component?

Comment: Sorry my mistake from trialing around, this was fixed